# How do I remove old mongo tools?

Tags: 20.04, mongodb

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to install latest mongodb

However I get this error:

```
➜  ~ 
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install         

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/52.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 47772 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.3.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
➜  ~ 


` trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1`

Can I just delete that or what?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix issue using dpkg in your case.

Force install mongodb tools package using dpkg.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb
```

Clean up all existing mongodb packages.

```
sudo apt purge mongodb*
```

After that install you should be able to install latest mongodb.